# Re-render picker items according the selection made by another picker in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

How to re-render picker items according the selection made by another picker in React-Native ?

var options =["Home","Savings","Car","GirlFriend"];

var cluster=[{item:"abc",key:"Home"},{item:"def",key:"Savings"},{item:"def",key:"Savings"},{item:"def",key:"Savings"}];

this.state = {

```
  selected_picker_1: "",
  selected_picker_2: "",
```

}

```
    onValueChangePicker1(value) {
      this.setState({
        selected_picker_1: value
      });
    }


    onValueChangePicker2(value) {
      this.setState({
        selected_picker_2: value
      });
    }


        <Picker 

          mode="dropdown"

          placeholder="Select One"

          style={{ width: undefined,backgroundColor:"white",marginTop:5}}
          selectedValue={this.state.selected_picker_1}
          onValueChange={this.onValueChangePicker1.bind(this)}>


          {options.map((item, index) => {
            return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={item}/>) 
        })}

        </Picker>







      <Picker 

          mode="dropdown"

          placeholder="Select One"

          style={{ width: undefined,backgroundColor:"white",marginTop:5}}
          selectedValue={this.state.selected_picker_2}
          onValueChange={this.onValueChangePicker2.bind(this)}>




          {cluster.map((item, index) => {

            renderIf(item.key===this.state.selected_picker_1) 
            {

              return(


           <Picker.Item label={item.item} value={index} key={index}/>


          )

            }



       })}



        </Picker>
```

// I need to re-render second picker with only items with key 'Home' when selects 'Home' on first picker.

Comment: what do you mean by picker? Date/time picker? Also it will be nice if you place the example code and error that you are facing. Otherwise you might not get a proper or helping answer.

Comment: I have done edits on my query. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved from this link
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/636

```
const items = ['Simon Mignolet','Nathaniel Clyne','Dejan Lovren','Mama Sakho','Emre Can'];

var BUTTONS = [
  'Option 0',
  'Option 1',
  'Option 2',
  'Delete',
  'Cancel',
];

export default class testBase2 extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      selected1: 'key1'

    }
  }

  getItems(val) {

    if (val === 'key1') 

   {
      
    return items;
    
   }

    else {
   
      return BUTTONS;
  
    }
  }

  onValueChange (value) 
  
{
   
     this.setState({
    
     selected1 : value
   
     });
  
 }

 onValueChange2 (value) 
 
{
  
  this.setState({
   
    selected2 : value
  
  });

}

  render() {

    return (

        <Container>
          <Header>
            <Left>
              <Button transparent>
                <Icon name="heart" size={20} color='red' />
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title>Hello</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right />
          </Header>
          <Content padder>
            <Picker
                iosHeader="Select one"
                mode="dropdown"
                selectedValue={this.state.selected1}
                onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}>
                <Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
                <Item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
                <Item label="Debit Card" value="key2" />
                <Item label="Credit Card" value="key3" />
                <Item label="Net Banking" value="key4" />
           </Picker>
           <Picker
               iosHeader="Select one"
               mode="dropdown"
               defaultLabel={"waiting"}
               selectedValue={this.state.selected2}
               onValueChange={this.onValueChange2.bind(this)}>
               {this.getItems(this.state.selected1).map((item, i) => {
                 console.log('item', item);
                return <Item label={item} key={`${i}+1`} value={i} />
               })}
          </Picker>
          </Content>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any specifics. Here's what I am assuming. Your second picker values ( the one which you need to alter based on selection ) are dependent on the first.

Firstly you need to identify which picker values are dependent. Following which the dependent values can be assigned to a state. Once set, the first picker will update the state on various selections and then your second picker will automatically get updated with those values.

That'll be a general answer to a general question :)

**EDIT**

You are checking the wrong values here        `renderIf(item.key===this.state.selected_picker_2)`. Your first picker sets the value in `this.state.selected_picker_1` whereas the results you are displaying are based on `this.state.selected_picker_2`.

Your condition should change to `renderIf(item.key===this.state.selected_picker_1)`

**EDIT 2**

Scope of `this` won't be available in the callback function of map. Define a constant as `const instance = this;` in the `render` method. And change your condition to `renderIf(item.key===instance.state.selected_picker_1)`

Comment: @Alby Please add implementation of `onValueChangeProject` method

Comment: sorry...there was some mistakes in variables..Please have a look again.

Comment: @Alby if only one function is controlling your both states, shouldn't it be `this.onValueChangePicker2.bind(this)` in your first picker?

Comment: There are two functions onValueChangePicker1,onValueChangePicker2

Comment: sorry that was a mistake in code import..Problem still exist.

Comment: @Alby please review your code. debugging is difficult when you already send a broken code

Comment: Updated as you said..but still not fixed.

Comment: @Alby https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171536/bug-fix lets discuss here

Comment: I don't have enough repuation to do chat. :(